# Python Web scraping using Selenium - "onclick" to download

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to write a script that uses selenium to download a file which consist of different NHL players information. I want to download a file for a set of different dates. The URL ending is the date such as: 
https://www.fantasycruncher.com/lineup-rewind/draftkings/NHL/2018-10-29

Moreover, there is a drop-down menu to select the numbers of rows shown per page.
Therefore, I create a loop to go through the set of dates and to show all of the rows on one page.

Finally, there is a drop-down menu called "actions" and one of the options is: Download Player List. Thus, I would like to generate a click on that option in my loop, that option will download a CSV files.

Here is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import date, timedelta 

chromedriver = 
("C:/Users/Michel/Desktop/python/package/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)


DFS = []
calendar= []
calendar.append("2018-10-30")
calendar.append("2018-10-31")
for d in calendar:
    driver.get("https://www.fantasycruncher.com/lineup-rewind/draftkings/NHL/"+ d)
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ff_length'))
    select.select_by_value("-1")
driver.close()
```

I am trying to generate the click after selecting "-1". Here is the source code for the option "Download Player list"

```
 <div class="table-actions-option" data-action="downloadPlayerlist" onclick="return true;">Download Player List</div>
```

How can I generate the click to download the list?

Then, I was planning to access the downloaded files in C:\Users\Downloads. Will it be possible or I will need to add some lines of code?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to show element `Download Player List` but there is delay so you need to wait when showing this.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from datetime import date, timedelta 

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chromedriver = ("C:/Users/Michel/Desktop/python/package/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Users/Downloads")
# or
# prefs = {'download.default_directory' : 'C:/Users/Downloads'}
# options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=options)


DFS = []
calendar= []
calendar.append("2018-10-30")
calendar.append("2018-10-31")
for d in calendar:
    driver.get("https://www.fantasycruncher.com/lineup-rewind/draftkings/NHL/"+ d)
    closeButton = driver.find_element_by_class_name('close-login-alert')
    closeButton.click()
    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ff_length'))
    select.select_by_value("-1")
    actions = driver.find_element_by_id('table-actions')
    actions.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH , '//div[@data-action="downloadPlayerlist"]')))
    downloadPlayerlist = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-action="downloadPlayerlist"]')
    downloadPlayerlist.click()

# remove the comment below to close the browser
#driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Could it be possible to choose where to save the downloaded files?